# calculate moving three-year average of grouped rows in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large dataset for which I am calculating numerous summary statistics, grouped by species and by year. Here's some toy code for setting up a dataframe:

```
species <- rep(c("Farfantepenaeus duorarum", "Menticirrhus littoralis",  "Ovalipes stephensoni", "Lolliguncula brevis", "Larimus fasciatus"), 4)
years <- rep(c(2007, 2013, 2001, 2013, 1994), 4)
lat <-c(33.9085, 34.6205, 33.7895, 33.8015, 29.9625, 35.1655, 34.7950, 29.5620, 32.8960, 32.2590, 33.1320, 32.9850, 34.6605, 34.0425, 32.8360, 32.6270, 32.0680, 31.7900, 34.1960, 30.7830)
testdf <- data.frame(species, years, lat)
```

The first statistic I'd like to calculate is an average of the highest 3 latitudes at which each species is found each year. I brute forced this with the following code, which I later joined back to the main df:

```
testtop3lat <- testdf %>%
  group_by(species, years) %>%
  top_n(3, lat) %>%
  mutate(top3lat = mean(lat))
```

The next task is where I'm stuck. For each combination of species and year, I'd like to calculate a moving three-year average of distance (latitude) covered. So, for every `species` and `years` combo, I want to calculate `[(latitude at year + 1) - (latitude at year - 1)] / 3`, and add it back as a column. Ultimately, I want each observation in the main df to have `top3lat` and `top3slope` columns with identical entries for each `species` and `years` combo.

I've been messing with `mutate` and with writing a custom function to map onto the original dataset, but neither is working so far. Suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT** sorry, that was not the most useful toy dataset. Working with the following observations for one species:

```
obsyears <- c(1980, 1980, 1980, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1982, 1982, 1982)
obslats <- c(38.5, 37, 39.2, 41.7, 40, 38.6, 41.2, 39.8, 38.7)
```

In 1981, desired output is `top3lat=40.1` (the average of 41.7, 40, and 38.6) **as a column for all row entries for that species in 1981**.

The *second* desired output for 1981 is `top3slope = [(top3lat[1982]-top3lat[1980])/3]` (yes, I know that's incorrect R language), which here would be `(39.9-38.23)/3 = 0.56`, **also as a column for all row entries for that species in 1981**.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you should be able to achieve what you are after within a `left_join` with `lead` and `lag`, all from [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr).

```
newdf <- testdf %>%
  left_join(
    testdf %>%
      group_by(species, years) %>%
      top_n(3, lat) %>%
      mutate(
        top3lat = mean(lat),
        top3slope = (lead(lat) - lag(lat)) / 3
      ) %>%
      na.omit %>%
      select(-lat),
    by = c("species", "years")
  ) %>%
  arrange(species, years, desc(lat))

newdf    
#                     species years     lat  top3lat  top3slope
# 1  Farfantepenaeus duorarum  2007 35.1655 34.06867 -0.2588333
# 2  Farfantepenaeus duorarum  2007 33.9085 34.06867 -0.2588333
# 3  Farfantepenaeus duorarum  2007 33.1320 34.06867 -0.2588333
# 4  Farfantepenaeus duorarum  2007 32.6270 34.06867 -0.2588333
# 5         Larimus fasciatus  1994 32.8360 31.95933 -0.4920000
# 6         Larimus fasciatus  1994 32.2590 31.95933 -0.4920000
# 7         Larimus fasciatus  1994 30.7830 31.95933 -0.4920000
# 8         Larimus fasciatus  1994 29.9625 31.95933 -0.4920000
# 9       Lolliguncula brevis  2013 34.1960 34.01333  0.1315000
# 10      Lolliguncula brevis  2013 34.0425 34.01333  0.1315000
# 11      Lolliguncula brevis  2013 33.8015 34.01333  0.1315000
# 12      Lolliguncula brevis  2013 32.8960 34.01333  0.1315000
# 13  Menticirrhus littoralis  2013 34.7950 34.13350 -0.5451667
# 14  Menticirrhus littoralis  2013 34.6205 34.13350 -0.5451667
# 15  Menticirrhus littoralis  2013 32.9850 34.13350 -0.5451667
# 16  Menticirrhus littoralis  2013 32.0680 34.13350 -0.5451667
# 17     Ovalipes stephensoni  2001 34.6605 33.41333 -0.6665000
# 18     Ovalipes stephensoni  2001 33.7895 33.41333 -0.6665000
# 19     Ovalipes stephensoni  2001 31.7900 33.41333 -0.6665000
# 20     Ovalipes stephensoni  2001 29.5620 33.41333 -0.6665000
```

This could be summarised further if dropping `lat`

```
newdf %>%
  select(-lat) %>%
  distinct

#                    species years  top3lat  top3slope
# 1 Farfantepenaeus duorarum  2007 34.06867 -0.2588333
# 2        Larimus fasciatus  1994 31.95933 -0.4920000
# 3      Lolliguncula brevis  2013 34.01333  0.1315000
# 4  Menticirrhus littoralis  2013 34.13350 -0.5451667
# 5     Ovalipes stephensoni  2001 33.41333 -0.6665000
```